# Problema con singleton y un api rest en Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, singleton

estoy trabajando en una aplicación con xamarin forms cross platform, bueno estoy usando un menú cuya información la obtiene de un api rest, para evitar que cada vez que se haga una llamada al menú se haga una consulta al api decidí usar un singleton, sin embargo no me retorna los datos del api, cabe mencionar que si no uso el singleton si trae los datos.
El código queda así

Model- CategoriesModel

```
 public partial class CategoriesModel
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("parent_id")]
    public long ParentId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("is_active")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("position")]
    public long Position { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("level")]
    public long Level { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("product_count")]
    public long ProductCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("children_data")]
    public List<CategoriesModel> ChildrenData { get; set; }
}

public partial class CategoriesModel
{
    public static CategoriesModel FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CategoriesModel>(json, PetandLove.Model.Converter.Settings);
}
```

Tengo un ViewModel que hace la consulta aun api rest que esta en una clase diferente.
ViewModel- MenuEspeciesViewModel

```
 ConectionApiMagento category = new ConectionApiMagento();
   public CategoriesModel categoryModel { get; set;}

    public MenuEspeciesViewModel()
    {
        getCategory();
    }

    public async void getCategory()
    {
        categoryModel = await category.GetCategories();
    }
```

Clase que hace la conexión- ConectionApiMagento.cs

```
public class ConectionApiMagento
{
    static readonly HttpClient cliente = new HttpClient();
    public async Task<CategoriesModel> GetCategories()
    {
            string url = "url";
            var resultado = await cliente.GetAsync(url);
            var json = resultado.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            CategoriesModel item = CategoriesModel.FromJson(json);
            return item;
    }
}
```

Singleton

```
public  class MenuSinlgeton
{

    #region Properties

    private static MenuSinlgeton _instance = null;
    public MenuEspeciesViewModel Especies { get; set;} 
    #endregion

    public  MenuSinlgeton()
    {
        Especies = new MenuEspeciesViewModel();
    }
    #region methods
    internal static MenuSinlgeton Instance()
    {
        if (_instance==null)
        {
            _instance = new MenuSinlgeton();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

La llamada al singleton la hago en el constructor de app.xmal.cs y en la clase donde se dibujan los datos.
Uso esta llamda `MenuSinlgeton Especies = MenuSinlgeton.Instance();`
En esencia me gustaría que el singleton tenga los datos que retorna el api para poder usarlos una infinidad de veces solo con una llamada a la api, no recibo errores solo cuando intento usar los datos que se supone debe traer el singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me tome la libertad de modificar tu código para que funcione. Espero te sirva o al menos para tomarlo como guía para una solución.

```
public class MenuSinlgeton
{
    public CategoriesModel CategoryModel { get; }

    private static MenuSinlgeton _instance = null;
    public MenuSinlgeton(CategoriesModel categoryModel)
    {
        CategoryModel = categoryModel;
    }

    public static MenuSinlgeton Instance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            ConectionApiMagento cnn = new ConectionApiMagento();

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //El motivo de este codigo es porque se esta llamando a un metodo async dentro de uno NO async
            var categorias = Task.Run(async () => await cnn.GetCategories());
            categorias.Wait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15));
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            _instance = new MenuSinlgeton(categorias.Result);
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    public class ConectionApiMagento
    {
        static readonly HttpClient cliente = new HttpClient();
        public async Task<CategoriesModel> GetCategories()
        {
            string url = "https://url.com/endpoint/?parameter=6";
            var resultado = await cliente.GetAsync(url);
            var json = resultado.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            CategoriesModel item = CategoriesModel.FromJson(json);
            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Luego puedes hacer la llamada

```
MenuSinlgeton Especies = MenuSinlgeton.Instance();
```

Comment: Algo me decía que era precisamente la llamada al método async solo que no sabia como hacerla, muchas gracias por la respuesta.